# How to get specific column name and apply style for that column in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

[table firmat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdAjf.jpg)

Here get whole sunday column in red color format except present show in green color in Sunday column
Here my date column data is dynamic
Using  jquery

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your table, you can add a `<colgroup>` to that and then style the column in that regard

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col span="3"></col> <!--Leave the first three columns alone-->
        <col style="background-color: red;"></col>
    </colgroup>
    <tr> ........... and then the rest of your HTML
```

But since you said the table is dynamic, maybe you can iterate the table cells per each row and find the number of that cell so that all the cells in that column can be applied the same style

```
<style>
    .cellColumn {
         background-color: red;
    }
</style>

<script>
    var table = document.querySelector("#table");
    var rows = table.querySelectorAll("tr");
    var numberOfCellsPerRow = rows[0].childElementCount;
    var cellNumberToChangeStyleFor;
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfCellsPerRow; i++) {
        //Iterate the first row looking for Sunday
        var cell = rows[0].children[i];
        if (cell.innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes("sunday") == true) {
            cellNumberToChangeStyleFor = i; //Record the cell number that we need to change
        }
    }
    //Now iterate every cell in every row and add that style to only that cell
    for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < numberOfCellsPerRow; k++) {
            if (k == cellNumberToChangeStyleFor) {
                var cell = rows[j].children[k];
                cell.classlist.add("cellColumn");
            }
        }
    }
```

Of course that was done off the top of my head so feel free to refine it and sorts

Comment: its not working .i just need to get "sunday" column in red color and another senario is In sunday coumn get all cells in red but if cell value is "present" then show this in green color only for that cell only and "absent" in red color

Comment: So for all cells, if the value is "Present" make it green, else make.it red???